# How to get a list of lines, with a list of polygons that they intersect?

Tags: postgis, polygon, line, intersect

I am a new user in a PostGIS environment and don't even know where to start.

I have two tables, one storing lines and the other storing polygons.
I to create a query that can be used to get a separate table where each line has a separate field listing the IDs of the polygons that the line touches.
The polygons are represented as a grid of squares. And the lines are a grid of streets.
[image: Green squares are polygons, others are lines]

As a result, we would like to get the following list

[image: result table]

Comment: You are probably looking for a cross lateral join. Can you provide some example data? I will be able to provide an answer then.

Answer (score 4):

This is generally solved using an `[INNER] JOIN`, or if you are also interested in lines that do *not* intersect any grid cells in the result set, a `LEFT JOIN`; you then want to `GROUP BY` your `line_id`s and collect the `name_polygon` with an `ARRAY_AGG` - the spatial predicate function you are looking for is `ST_Intersects`:

```
SELECT
  l.line_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT p.polygon_name) AS polygon_names
FROM
  <lines> AS l
  JOIN
  <polygon> AS p
    ON ST_Intersects(l.geom, p.geom)
GROUP BY
  l.line_id
;
```

to only return *lines that actually intersect at least one polygon*, or

```
SELECT
  l.line_id,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT p.polygon_name) AS polygon_names
FROM
  <lines> AS l
  LEFT JOIN
  <polygon> AS p
    ON ST_Intersects(l.geom, p.geom)
GROUP BY
  l.line_id
;
```

to also *include those that do not intersect any polygons* (receiving `NULL` as `polygon_names`).

---

**Considerations:**

- if you expect that the majority (or all) rows in `<lines>` will get returned, and especially

  1. if you need to return more than one column, or others than those covered by the `PRIMARY KEY` or any multi-column index
  2. if you need to apply transformations to any of the returned values from `<polygon>`

  it is more performant to run a `[LEFT|CROSS JOIN] LATERAL` to avoid the costly extended `GROUP BY` list:

  ```
  SELECT
    l.line_id,
    g.polygon_names
  FROM
    <lines> AS l
    CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT p.polygon_name) AS polygon_names
      FROM
        <polygon> AS p
      WHERE
        ST_Intersects(l.geom, p.geom)
    ) AS g
  ;
  ```

  to only return *lines that actually intersect at least one polygon*, or

  ```
  SELECT
    l.line_id,
    g.polygon_names
  FROM
    <lines> AS l
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT
        ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT p.polygon_name) AS polygon_names
      FROM
        <polygon> AS p
      WHERE
        ST_Intersects(l.geom, p.geom)
    ) AS g ON TRUE
  ;
  ```

  to also *include those that do not intersect any polygons* (receiving `NULL` as `polygon_names`)
- `ST_Intersects` (as well as most other 2D spatial predicate functions) are running against the *GEOS* backend, which has recently been enhanced with prepared geometry caching that boosts the underlying computations; this has a massive effect if you expect to have *many* overlaps with a (few) potentially large and complex geometries *each*.
  In all others cases it is worth comparing performance to the native and highly optimized `ST_DWithin` function with `0` distance - simply replace `ST_Intersects(l.geom, p.geom)` with `ST_DWithin(l.geom, p.geom, 0)` in the above queries - on a test with 100k random segments over 1M grid cells, the factor of execution time is almost 3:1 in favor of `ST_DWithin`

---

Run any of the above queries within a `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE <name> AS (
  <query>
);
```

to get a new table with the results.

Comment: Note that perfromance depends greatly on the presence of a spatial (e.g. `GIST`) index on the `<polygon>` geometry column!